# How to select a directory route via Dialog Form ON ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, dialog, directory

I need to place a button which will open a Dialog form, on which you will be able to browse Windows directories to select a ROUTE (example c:\Windows) and place all the folder's available files on a listbox.

This is done on a Web Application on ASP.NET. I have looked for examples of browsers, some are for windows forms, but I haven't found one for ASP.NET (I am aware that there is fileupload or others that are similar, but those, you have to select a file, where in my example I only need to specify a route).

Hope you can help me

Comment: Basically the Web Applications will be given access to the site's directory and the user documents. However, you can try using Environment [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.100).aspx]

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific control available in ASP.NET to achieve this, but you can derive it from windows form controls. Please take a look at the example - http://www.netomatix.com/FolderBrowser.aspx